# Set up ssl correctly in lighttpd but when i restart it, https will time out?

Tags: linux, ssl, webserver, amazon-ami

I have a simple lighttpd server that works:

```
server.port = 80
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.pemkey = "path/to/pemfile.pem"
}
```

and then run `/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart` but when going so the standard url, the port works as expected (:80), but when trying to navigate to the https version of the site it gives me a timeout error.

Im not getting config file errors when figuring out the pem file, so that is all correct; created by certbot-auto

I have a bunch of other configurables in the config file, but i thought these were the important ones.

I know if i remove `server.port = 80` the regular site doesnt open at all.

Comment: Have you checked that access to port 443 from outside is allowed to the system, i.e. no firewall is blocking the access?

Comment: No, i have not tried that.  I will google that and see whats up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into the AMI console, and click to your instance.  After that, in your Description Tab, you will see Security Groups.  You can see the rules for your group, but you can click on your group.  You will navigate to a new page.  After navigation, you will see a list of security rule groups.  Edit the security group you want to use to add a rule allowing port 443.

After doing that you go log into your instance, and go to your lighttpd.config file and set it up by way of:

```
server.port = 443
ssl.engine  = "enable"
ssl.pemkey  = "path/to/pemkey.pem"
```

Now the other trick is that when using certbot you will get a few different files.  You will need to join two files together.  you can run `cat privkey.pem cert.pem > pemkey.pem` which will join the 2 files together and you can set the result as the `ssl.pemkey`.

After you configure the AWS firewall rules, and adjust the config file the last thing you need to do is restart lighttpd

`/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart` will do the trick and if all works right, the secure version of your application is now available.

The only thing you need to be wary of is the fact that you do not have forwarding from non secure to secure, so there are 2 separate access points.  You can then modify that with adjusting the config file even more.